# PHP How to target a specific key in a hash array and output different HTML?

Tags: php, html, arrays

I have a hash array in PHP and need to iterate through it and pull out the details but also target a specific key and use that information differently.

What I am trying to do is display the information for each user in the browser but I want IconColour to not display to the screen but build an icon, coloured depending on that value.

I'm building the array with:

```
$results_array [] = array("Name"=>$fullname, "telephone"=>$telephone, "updated"=>$lastupdated, "LRNumber"=>$tacticalcallsign, "IconColour"=>$iconcolour);
```

To pull this information out and display to the browser I am using:

```
foreach($results_array as $row => $value){
 echo "\t<div class=\"responder-info-parent\">\n";   
    foreach($value as $row2 => $value2) {
        echo "\t\t<div class=\"responder-info\">" . $value2 . "</div>\n";
}
echo "\t</div>\n";
}
```

which is giving me:

```
<div class="responder-info-parent">
    <div class="responder-info">Firstname Lastname</div>
    <div class="responder-info">01234567896</div>
    <div class="responder-info">1 hours ago</div>
    <div class="responder-info">LR066</div>
    <div class="responder-info">amber</div>
</div><!-- close parent-->
```

I would like an amber icon displayed instead of the word amber.

eg:

```
<div class="responder-info-parent">
        <div class="responder-info">First Name</div>
        <div class="responder-info">123456789</div>
        <div class="responder-info">1 hours ago</div>
        <div class="responder-info">LR066</div>
        <div class="responder-info"><img src="/images/amber-icon.png"></div>
    </div><!-- close parent-->
```

So. My understanding is that I would need to test for a specific key (IconColour) and if that matches then output different html from the other keys.

And that is where I am stuck. I know what I need to do and have searched for targeting a specific key in a hash array but am yet to find a solution. Although I know that as soon as I post this (and get down voted) I will instantly come across the answer ;-)

For completeness. This is a var_dump of my $results_array

Thank you for your help.

```
array(7) {
  [0]=>
  array(5) {
    ["Name"]=>
    string(15) "First Name"
    ["telephone"]=>
    string(11) "123456789"
    ["updated"]=>
    string(11) "1 hours ago"
    ["LRNumber"]=>
    string(5) "LR066"
    ["IconColour"]=>
    string(5) "amber"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(5) {
    ["Name"]=>
    string(12) "First Name"
    ["telephone"]=>
    string(11) "01234568796"
    ["updated"]=>
    string(11) "4 hours ago"
    ["LRNumber"]=>
    string(5) "LR011"
    ["IconColour"]=>
    string(5) "amber"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(5) {
    ["Name"]=>
    string(19) "First Name"
    ["telephone"]=>
    string(11) "01234568796"
    ["updated"]=>
    string(10) "1 days ago"
    ["LRNumber"]=>
    string(5) "LR005"
    ["IconColour"]=>
    string(4) "grey"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(5) {
    ["Name"]=>
    string(8) "First Name"
    ["telephone"]=>
    string(5) "LR076"
    ["updated"]=>
    string(11) "80 days ago"
    ["LRNumber"]=>
    string(11) "01234568796"
    ["IconColour"]=>
    string(4) "grey"
  }
  [4]=>
  array(5) {
    ["Name"]=>
    string(14) "First Name"
    ["telephone"]=>
    string(11) "01234568796"
    ["updated"]=>
    string(11) "1 hours ago"
    ["LRNumber"]=>
    string(5) "LR036"
    ["IconColour"]=>
    string(5) "amber"
  }
  [5]=>
  array(5) {
    ["Name"]=>
    string(11) "First Name"
    ["telephone"]=>
    string(11) "01234568796"
    ["updated"]=>
    string(13) "0 minutes ago"
    ["LRNumber"]=>
    string(5) "LR002"
    ["IconColour"]=>
    string(5) "green"
  }
  [6]=>
  array(5) {
    ["Name"]=>
    string(13) "First Name"
    ["telephone"]=>
    string(11) "01234568796"
    ["updated"]=>
    string(11) "7 hours ago"
    ["LRNumber"]=>
    string(5) "LR003"
    ["IconColour"]=>
    string(5) "amber"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if ($row2 == 'IconColour') {
    echo "\t\t<div class=\"responder-info\"><img src=\"/images/" . $value2 . "-icon.png\"></div>\n";
} else {
    // whatever you have now
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In a [foreach loop](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) you have a key and a value. You can check if the current key == "IconColour" and show image instead of just echoing the value. Than you can echo the color (value) and hard code other part of the name of the image if you have all the icons named like: "color"-icon.png. Example:

```
$results_array [] = array("Name"=>'First Name', "telephone"=>'123456789', "updated"=>'1 hours ago', "LRNumber"=>'LR066', "IconColour"=>'amber');

foreach($results_array as $key => $value){
    echo "\t<div class=\"responder-info-parent\">\n";   
    foreach($value as $key2 => $value2) {
       if ($key2 == "IconColour") {
           echo "\t\t<div class=\"responder-info\"><img src=\"/images/" . $value2 . "-icon.png\"</div>\n"; 
       } else {
           echo "\t\t<div class=\"responder-info\">" . $value2 . "</div>\n";
       }

   }
   echo "\t</div>\n";
}
```